# Sikuli click on the wrong thing

Tags: javascript, java, sikuli, sikuli-script

Hello I'm writtin a script with Sekuli.

But when I write example: screen.click(test.png). It happens that Sikuli just click on the wrong screenshot. I don't understand why. How can I tell to Sikuli to be more accurate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something so if you use .exact() sikuli will "sets the minimum Similarity to 0.99 which means exact match"